# Java exception, RegEx

Tags: java, regex, exception

i'm new to java programming and i'm trying to validate an email value using RegEx, the program should throw an exception when the user provides a wrong value, i managed to do this with an if-else. However, when i try to handle the error using a try-catch block the RegEx does not work anymore and the wrong value gets displayed anyways. How can i solve this?

here's the code

```java
try {
    String emailRegex = "^(.+)@(.+).(.+)$";
    if(email.matches(emailRegex)) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);
        System.out.println(pattern.matcher(email).matches());
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Comment: I don't see any try-catch block. Btw, you don't need start and end anchors with `matches()`.

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: Regex works. But you print the message from the exception. You didn't provide the details of your regex problem to the exception. What do you expect it to print?

Comment: I would recommend that you don't use such a pattern in general: throw an exception in your code and in the same piece of code (method) catch that exception and do something with it.
Exceptions are meant to communicate exceptional situations from callee to caller. 
If you handle the error in the same code you could easily place the output message inside your `else` branch. (Once you `catch` the exception, it will not be processed any further.)

Comment: Also note that that regular expression matches almost anything, as long as an `@` is present. For instance, it also matches `.@...`.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression rejects valid email addresses. Even if you did fix it. For example, `foo@bar` is actually valid (top-level domains can contain `MX` records. A few do!). This is the general formula for 'is it valid email':

- Does it contain spaces? If yes, reject.
- Does it contain at least 1 `@`? If no, reject.
- Is the last `@` at position 0 (i.e. at the start), or at the end? Reject.

Otherwise, pass. There are a few invalid emails that would nevertheless pass, but this is by and large no problem: `foo@bar` is not *really* legal, but the only real way to know that, is to send an email to it and request the user click a link inside it before they can continue. No regexp is ever going to figure out if the email address entered by a user is in fact a valid email address, let alone an email address that belongs to that user, hence, there is no real point in trying to go any further than that. You're attempting to catch honest typoes, not actually validate anything, because that is impossible. Note that it can easily become legal tomorrow - someone just needs to set up the `bar` top level domain and make sure there's an MX record for it in its DNS registration and voila. `foo@bar` is now legal.

Your regex is close to this ideal; you just want `^.+@.+$`

NB: If you want to break spec and reject any email addresses to top-level domains, your regex is broken. Your intent is clearly to want `foo@a.b`, but you don't do that - that middle `.`, nestled between `(.+)`, is still a regex dot operator, meaning: "any character". You'd want `\\.` for that instead. But, don't - as I said, TLDs are themselves rare as mail servers, but valid according to spec!

Fix this and your code 'works', but note that your code can go only one of two ways:

- The regexp matches, in which case you *again* run the string through the regexp (seems rather pointless to do it twice!), and then trivially prints 'true'. The entire `Pattern pattern = ...; System.out.println(...)` might as well be `System.out.println("true");` - that's what it will *always* do - yes, the regexp that just matched, is still going to match, of course.
- The regexp does not match, in which case we get to the else block, which throws an exception. This then goes to the catch block which can only catch this (as nothing else throws IllegalArgumentEx here), and prints the 'localized message', which is `null` here.

So, this code prints `true` if it matches, and `null` if it does not. That seems.. weird. And is needlessly complicated if that's what you wanted.

Better:

```java
class Test {
  private static final Pattern EMAIL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^.+@.+$");

  public static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    return EMAIL_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
      System.out.print("Enter an email address: ");
      String line = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
      if (line.isEmpty()) System.exit(0);
      if (isValidEmail(line)) {
        System.out.println("Valid");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Not valid");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The try/catch block do not add anything useful here. You use try/catch when you want to transfer an error condition across method calls, not within the same method call, and not when the only meaningful data you can convey is a boolean flag. If that's all you have ('valid' or 'not valid'), almost always you just want a boolean.

If you really want the exception instead:

```java
class Test {
  private static final Pattern EMAIL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^.+@.+$");

  public static void validateEmail(String email) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (!EMAIL_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Email '" + email + "' is not valid");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
      System.out.print("Enter an email address: ");
      String line = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
      if (line.isEmpty()) System.exit(0);
      try {
        validateEmail(line);
        System.out.println("Valid");
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
}
```